# どこにあるか分からないファイルが原因で、git pushがエラーになる

Tags: git, github

SwiftとXcodeで開発をしています。
バージョン管理のため、GitHubへgit pushしようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。

以下のコマンドを実行すると、エラーになります。

```
cd "/Users/gncc/Documents/TestAppMain/TestApp"
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/gncc/TestApp.git
git push -u origin main
```

エラーメッセージは以下のようなものです。

```
remote: error: Trace: xxxxxxxxxx
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: TestApp/Test.framework/TestFramework is 475.69 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/gncc/TestApp.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
```

「`TestApp/Test.framework/TestFramework`のファイルサイズが大きすぎるから`git lfs`を使ってね」というエラーだと思うのですが、TestApp/Test.framework/TestFrameworkのフォルダごと削除した後に、`git add`と`git commit`と`git push`をしても同じ内容のエラーが出ます。

`git lfs`はインストール済で、ファイルの大きなフォルダは以下のようにして`git lfs`の対象にしています。

```
cd "/Users/gncc/Documents/TestAppMain/TestApp"
git lfs track "/**"
git add .gitattributes
```

Mac上で「command + shift + . 」で隠しフォルダ、隠しファイルを表示してもファイルは隠されていないようです。

どうしたら、原因となっているファイルを削除する、もしくは削除せずにそのままGitHubへpushできますかるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

TestAppディレクトリの下にTest.frameworkを再度追加し、

```
cd TestApp
git rm -fr Test.framework
```

してからコミットして下さい。
これは既に`git`管理下にある`Test.framework`を`git`管理下から削除するコマンドです。

これで`git push`は成功すると思います。
次に、`Test.framework`はプロジェクトに追加したいけれど`git`で管理しないように
`.gitignore`ファイルに

```
Test.framework/
```

としてから、`.gitignore`ファイルをコミットして下さい。
`.gitignore`ファイルはあればそれに一行追加、なければ、`.git`フォルダーと同じ階層に`.gitignore`ファイルを作成し、そこに上記を記述して下さい。

Comment: git rm -r　を使用した後にcommitとpushをしても、gitignoreを使用しても同じエラーが出るようです。

Comment: 最初のコミット前に.gitignoreを編集してTest.frameworkを管理からはずしたgitリポジトリを作ってみて下さい

Comment: 他の何をやってもだめだったのですが、フレームワークのファイルをコピーしてくる時に「copy item if needed」のチェックをOFFにしてコピーしてきたら治りました。